# Action during onMessageReceived() in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

I want to do something everytime `onMessageReceived()` triggers specifically. I want to send text messages. I'm not really sure if it's a great idea to put a code in `FirebaseMessagingService` that runs a task that might take a little while to finish (number of messages sent may vary). Do you guys have any recommendations on how or where to run the task? Should I create another service for this task? I'm not really well versed on this side of Android Development. Any response is much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseMessagingService` is a `Service`, it doesn't run on UI thread, so you can run tasks that are meant to be run in background threads.

> Do you guys have any recommendations on how or where to run the task?

To make code readable, I'd suggest you to create another class to handle the task. Something like `MessageSender.sent(data)`. So the code will be a lot easier to read.

> Should I create another service for this task?

It's not necessary, but when looking from the [SOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) perspective, it's better to  separate task. So it'll be more better to create something like `MessageSenderService` and invoke it from `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Anyone can correct me if am wrong. :)

Comment: Hello thank you for the response, will try doing this